# How to create a share target app for Windows Phone in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to know how make my app able to receive links from other apps with the Share option of Windows Phone. I've heard of editing the `package.appxmanifest` file but I can't find it and can't find out how to create it (read this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871367.asp)).
If anyone can help me... help me please !

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally found where I was wrong : if you have the same problem, upgrade the solution to Windows Phone 8.1 (updating Visual Studio to Update 2 before) and then the file will magically appear in the Solution Explorer. You're welcome.